# Show button after two clicks Flash CS6 As2

Tags: actionscript-2

I want to make  my "button 3" visible after click in "button 1" and "button 2". How can I do it?

I have not tried any code cause I have no idea how to do this :p

Comment: Try to code something, it's really very very easy to do that. You have just to know when clicking a button ( button 1 or 2 ) if the other one has been already pressed to show the 3rd button. That's all !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use global variables for each bt and a listener for the last btn, for example, when you click bt1 replace the original value of the variable, lets say:

bt1 = 0;   now could be    bt1 = 1;

you write these somewhere in your first frame o in the root, just remember to point the right timeline if you write it outside your current timeline.

Let's say you write in the first frame of the root:

```
bt1=0;
bt2=0;

mybt._visible = false; //here you turn it off

onEnterFrame = function(){
    if (bt1 == 1 && bt2 == 1){
        trace("Say it Worked");
        mybt._visible = true; //and here you turn it on
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }
}
```

Then each button must have something like:

```
on (release) {
    _root.bt1 = 1; // or 2, depends on what button it is
   // Your Actions
}
```

And your invisible button must have an instance name, in this case: "mybt"